# Not getting the order I want when reversing the words in a string

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, loops, for-loop

I am currently learning TypeScript and I am trying to create a function that accepts a string parameter and reverses each word in the string.

Here is what I am looking for in my return:

```
"This is an example!" ==> "sihT si na !elpmaxe"
```

This is a solution I created. I am trying to avoid built-in methods.

```
export function reverseWords(str: string): string {
  var newStr = "";
  str.split("");
  for(var i = str.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
    newStr += str[i];
  }
  return newStr;
}

reverseWords("Hi. How are you?")
```

This code gives me the following:

```
 "This is an example!" ==> !elpmaxe na si sihT
```

I am looking for this:

```
 "This is an example!" ==> "sihT si na !elpmaxe"
```

Can someone explain to me what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: `"This is an example!".split(' ').map(word => [...word].reverse().join('')).join(' ');`

Comment: Just in case you didn't realise, this is also a problem on codewars where you can test your solution and see responses from others:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5259b20d6021e9e14c0010d4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is good, but it reverse the string it gets, Just add another function which uses your function to reverse just the words:

```
export function reverseStringWords(str: string): string {
    var words = str.split(" ");
    var revWords = words.map(function(word){
        return reverseWords(word);    
    });
    return revWords.join(" ");
}
```

You can rename your function to `reverseWord` so it will make more sense in the context.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to reverse the *whole string*, but only each word inside the string, preserving each word's relative position. You could split by spaces first, then reverse each substring:

```js
const reverse = str => str
  .split(' ')
  .map(word => [...word].reverse().join(''))
  .join(' ');
console.log(reverse("This is an example!"));
```

or if you really want to do it manually, assuming `split` is allowed:

```js
const reverse = str => {
  const words = str.split(' ');
  const outWords = [];
  for (const word of words) {
    let letter = '';
    for (let i = word.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      letter += word[i];
    }
    outWords.push(letter);
  }
  return outWords.join(' ');
};
console.log(reverse("This is an example!"));
```